# How can I improve the performance of a SAP BO Webi 4.0 with Bex query as back end?

Tags: business-objects

I am generating a Webi report using Bex query as source (BICS connectivity). Seeing performance issue in the report as I am doing all the calculations using variables in Webi.

I would like to know any performance gain if we move the calculations to the BEX query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are the key points to remember,
1. Delegate all the relevant/complex calculations in BEX side by using CKF/RKF
2. Keep all the filters in BEX query rather than keeping in WEBi
3. Filter using Indexing for all the Webi.